# html2canvas dynamically rendered div

Tags: reactjs, html2canvas, react-google-maps

I am trying to use `html2canvas` (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) to take a screenshot of my page that contains a google maps view, but I am running into an issue where the resulting screenshot is white, except for the marker. What (possibly) complicates the issue is that I am (trying to) creating a React application.

I use this code to take the screenshot:

```
takeScreenshot = () => {
    let googleMapsView = document.querySelector('.google-map');

    html2canvas(googleMapsView).then((canvas) => {
        let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        console.log(imgData);
    });
}
```

This is the page I'm trying to take a screenshot of:
[image: Page to screenshot]

The code above generates the following image:

[image: Resulting screenshot]

As you can see, it generates the screenshot and captures the marker and the bottom "Map Data ©2018 Google" however, the resulting screenshot is still blank.

In the documentation on their Github, I see an option to preload here: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/wiki/Documentation#preload-content

However, this seems to have been removed from the library since the `0.5.0 beta` version - they're now in `1.0.0 alpha`, so going back that far to such an outdated library is not really an option.

How can I tell html2canvas to wait for the GMaps component to be rendered, before taking the screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add param useCORS to use it with google maps, in your case:

```
takeScreenshot = () => {
let googleMapsView = document.querySelector('.google-map');

html2canvas(googleMapsView, {useCORS: true}).then((canvas) => {
    let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log(imgData);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put your code inside the google map listener

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    // do something only the first time the map is loaded
    takeScreenshot = () => {
        let googleMapsView = document.querySelector('.google-map');

        html2canvas(googleMapsView).then((canvas) => {
            let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            console.log(imgData);
         });
     }
});
```

See also the events section in the [Google Maps Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/#Map).

Comment: Sadly I couldn't get this to work. The end result is still a white image. Where should I register this listener? Is `componentDidMount` the appropriate place?

Comment: you should register it after you instantiate the map